# Python list certain files in different folders

Tags: python

I've got 2 folders, each with a different CSV file inside (both have the same format):
[image]

I've written some python code to search within the "C:/Users/Documents" directory for CSV files which begin with the word "File"

```
import glob, os

inputfile = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/Documents/"):
    for datafile in files:
        if datafile.startswith("File") and datafile.endswith(".csv"):
            inputfile.append([os.path.join(root, datafile)])

print(inputfile)
```

That almost worked as it returns:

```
[['C:/Users/Documents/Test A\\File 1.csv'], ['C:/Users/Documents/Test B\\File 2.csv']]
```

Is there any way I can get it to return this instead (no sub list and shows / instead of \):

```
['C:/Users/Documents/Test A/File 1.csv', 'C:/Users/Documents/Test B/File 2.csv']
```

The idea is so I can then read both CSV files at once later, but I believe I need to get the list in the format above first.

Comment: instead of `inputfile.append([os.path.join(root, datafile)])` ; use `inputfile.append(os.path.join(root, datafile))` without the square brackets. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah that's worked, just the last issue left where it's returning `['C:/Users/Documents/Test A\\File 1.csv', 'C:/Users/Documents/Test B\\File 2.csv']` but I want it to return `['C:/Users/Documents/Test A/File 1.csv', 'C:/Users/Documents/Test B/File 2.csv']` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, I will paste an option here.
I made use of `os.path.abspath` to get the the path before join.

Have a look and see if it works.

```
import os
filelist = []
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk("C:/Users/Documents/"):
    for datafile in files:
        if datafile.startswith("File") and datafile.endswith(".csv"):
            filePath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, datafile))
            filelist.append(filePath)

filelist
```

Result:

```
['C:/Users/Documents/Test A/File 1.csv','C:/Users/Documents/Test B/File 2.csv']
```

Comment: Is there a way to get them into a list though?  Notice in my original code I was appending into the list and not printing the values

Comment: yes, I have amended the script to give you a `filelist` list using `append`.